# managing right and left clicks in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, events, mouseevent

I have a complex Qt GUI, where one part of the GUI displays a plot with various data points.

When currently left or right clicking on the plot, it returns the x-y values at the location of the click. My job is to update this so that left-click still does the same thing, but right-click selects the nearest data point and opens a context menu allows me to remove said data point. The idea is to manually be able to remove outliers.

UPDATED: I THINK that I have found the segment of code currently responsible for returning x-y values:

```
void plotspace::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent*event)
{
    double trange = _timeonright - _timeonleft;
    int twidth = width();
    double tinterval = trange/twidth;

    int xclicked = event->x();

    _xvaluecoordinate = _timeonleft+tinterval*xclicked;



    double fmax = Data.plane(X,0).max();
    double fmin = Data.plane(X,0).min();
    double fmargin = (fmax-fmin)/40;
    int fheight = height();
    double finterval = ((fmax-fmin)+4*fmargin)/fheight;

    int yclicked = event->y();

    _yvaluecoordinate = (fmax+fmargin)-finterval*yclicked;

    cout<<"Time(s): "<<_xvaluecoordinate<<endl;
    cout<<"Flux: "<<_yvaluecoordinate<<endl;
    cout << "timeonleft= " << _timeonleft << "\n";

    returncoordinates();

    emit updateCoordinates();

}
```

Like I said, I need to turn this into left-clicking performing the same action, and right-clicking opening a context menu. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: BTW your background is irrelevant. SO judges on quality of question, not background info.

Comment: You are not at the event code.  You can put your cursor on `coordinatevalues` and press Ctrl+Shift+U to  find the usages (where this function is used). Those could be closer to the event code.  When you find it, place the code in your question and someone will be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check which mouse button was used. Generally I prefer to deal with the `mouseReleaseEvent` instead of `mousePressEvent` as it replicates better the conventional mouse behavior. But both events work. An exemple:

```
void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
  if (e->button() == Qt::LeftButton)    // Left button...
  {
    // Do something related to the left button
  }
  else if (e->button() == Qt::RightButton)   // Right button...
  {
    // Do something related to the right button
  }
}
```

You can also deal with the `Qt::MidButton` if so you wish.